# 2021 Toyota Tacoma 4hi @ 70mph

Tags: toyota, truck, 4wd, tacoma

I just bought a 2021 Toyota Tacoma sr5.

I wanted to test the 4 wheel drive switching on the fly. I switched to 4hi at 40mph. Worked perfectly. I got distracted and forgot to switch back to 2w. I drove in 4hi for about 10 miles at 70 mph and made 2 somewhat sharp turns at below 20 mph and went through a round about before I noticed.

Is this something I should worry about? What are some things to pay attention to after the fact?

Comment: Many newer 4wd will drop out above a certain speed. Check the owners manual.

Comment: My 2018 TRD Off Road won't switch into 4WD above 65mph, but is OK being in 4WD above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain in the transfer case can take a lot more abuse than 10 miles, even with a few sharp turns. Nothing popped, which means everything is fine. Just pay attention next time.
4HI or 4LO modes are only to be used in slippery conditions (snow, gravel, etc.), and you definitely don't want to drive high speed on firm pavement with transfer case and no center differential, like those Tacomas.